# Unclear type error resulting in failing plot

Tags: python, types, seaborn, typeerror

I have a list of columns for which I have ensured that the data types are correct:

| Date1 | Date2 | Geleverde Kg | Oderhvh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-01 | 3000.0 | 3000.0 |
| 2021-03-02 | 2021-03-04 | 15000.0 | 15000.0 |

I changed the datatypes (note: categorical and numerical refer to a list of column names):

```
orders[categorical] = orders[categorical].astype('str')
orders[numeric_non_date] = orders[numeric_non_date].values.astype(float)
```

The schema looks correct

[image]

However, when I make a kde plot, I get a type error:

```
ax = sns.kdeplot (data = orders, x = "Geleverde Kg")
```

**TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]**

What is going on here? This feature doesn't have a datetime datatype, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of your data or error messages. You can include [code that creates a dataframe or the output of `print(df)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (or of a few rows and columns that allow to reproduce the example)

Comment: Also if you specify data and x but not y, it’s likely seaborn will try to plot all columns including your datetime columns `Leveringsdatum` etc.

Comment: Hi, I have included two lines of data. Hopefull that helps.

Comment: For a kde plot you only have to define an X column, so that should not be the problem. It works perfectly fine on other dataeets I work on, so it must have soemthing to do with the data.

Comment: Do you get the same error with `sns.kdeplot(orders['Geleverde Kg'])` ?

Comment: Not the same error, but another error : TypeError: kdeplot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Comment: Then `sns.kdeplot(data=orders[['Geleverde Kg']], x=['Geleverde Kg'])` − basically remove the other columns from the equation. Also my kdeplot is fine with having just one column passed in, you might want to add versions of seaborn / pandas / numpy / python into your post.